# embedd webpage into html document not working

Tags: html

I am trying to embedd a webpage from a cisco satellite device into a div tag of my webpage but I am getting the following problem

The page loads properly with the logon screen but as soon as I enter the login details it does not login byut instead stays on the login screen. I have tried both div and Iframe and both give me the same results. However when i access the device directly on IE or Chrome it works fine. The problem is only within my iframe or div.

My samle code is below however since you dont have access to the device you may not be able to see it working.. A shot in the dark here just asking you all to please give me some stuff to try out

```
    <!<doctype html>

    <html lang="en">

    <body>


        <div style="margin: 0 auto; width: 100%; height: 100%;">

            <object type="text/html" data="http://192.168.10.107/"
                style="width: 100%; height: 100%; margin: 1%;"> </object>

        </div>

    </body>

    </html>
```

I also tried this with iframes as under but that also failed to work

```
       <html>


        <iframe src="http://192.168.10.107" sandbox ="allow-same-origin   allow-scripts allow-popups allow-forms" width=100% height =100%></iframe>

    </html>
```

Comment: Just to clarify.. What is happening is the login window from the cisco device appears inside the div container but when I enter the username and password it does not take it. It gives me the log in screen again. Is this because of some security in place oris something I am doing wrong. I read somewhere that it could be an htpps page

Answer (score 0):

Here I have a page that is like the one you want I guess.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>MyTitle</title>
</head>

<frameset rows="0,*" border="0">
<frame name="header" scrolling="no" noresize target="main">
<frame name="main" src="http://192.168.10.107/">
<noframes>
<body>

</body>
</noframes>
</frameset>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help.. But this also does not take the page past the login screen..  IS there a browser security thing where login forms cant be submitted within an iframe and if yes is there a work around for it.. Security is not a problem as it is an internal network and does not need to be secure.